# Loading a variable into an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, echo

I have a PHP code as follows:

1 file contains this:

```
    <?php
$max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
?>
<div class="cartSummary">
<?php echo $lang['CARTSTATUS']; ?>
</div>
```

The other file contains this:

```
$lang['CARTSTATUS'] = "Tiene <a href='../cart/shoppingCart.php'>".$max." productos </a>en su cesta de compra";
```

The problem is that the outcome only shows the plain text, the `$max` variable is not printed.

Do you see any issue with loading $max into the array $lang I am using?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing `$max` is undefined when you set `$lang['CARTSTATUS'];`. Care to show us where you set it?

Comment: php cannot reach back in time and retroactively modify a string which was created using a variable which hasn't been defined yet. if $max didn't exist at the time the cartstatus was set, it will **NOT** get modified when you do eventually change $max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `$lang['CARTSTATUS']` you already reed to have `$max` defined. By your extracted code, it looks like you first set `$lang['CARTSTATUS']` and then `$max`

Answer (score 0):

Let your other file have assignment like this:

```
$lang['CARTSTATUS'] = 'Tiene <a href=\'../cart/shoppingCart.php\'> $max productos </a>en su cesta de compra';
```

Then in file1 have code like this:

```
<?php
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    $tmp = $lang['CARTSTATUS'];
    eval("\$tmp = \"$tmp\";");
    $lang['CARTSTATUS'] = $tmp;
?>
<div class="cartSummary">
<?php echo $lang['CARTSTATUS']; ?>
</div>
```

It will output your expected string.

I usually don't provide any answer with eval in it but this seems to be safe use of PHP's much criticized [eval function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).